# Checking whether array contains incremental elements if one is removed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to write a function that checks whether or not an array would be incremental if we were to remove one element from the array. So for example an array like

```
[1,3,4,2,8]
```

Would return true because if we remove 2, the array would be incremental ie [1,3,4,8]

To solve this I created a function that iterates through the array, checks whether n is less than n+1 creating an array of true and false values depending on whether the element we are iterating through meets the condition stated.

In cases where n+1 is less than or equal to n; I then have another condition that checks whether n+1 is less than n-1, returning 'very false' in this instance.

I then want to return false if my new Array indicates that removing one element will not leave me with an array of incremental values. I check for by checking whether;
i.) my new array contains more than one false value
ii.) my new array contains the value 'very false' only in instances if very false is not the last element in my array
iii.) my array contains both very false and false

Struggling to get this logic to work. I added a few test cases I am struggling to get right

```
function solution(sequence) {
    let newArr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
        sequence[i] < sequence[i+1] ? newArr.push(true) 
            : sequence[i+1] <= sequence[i-1] ? newArr.push('very false')
                :newArr.push(false)
    }
    return (newArr.filter(i => i === false).length) > 1 || ( (newArr.includes('very false')) && (newArr[newArr.length - 1] !== 'very false')) || ( newArr.includes(false) && newArr.includes('very false')) ? false : true;
}
//TEST CASES
let one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6] //I get this right
let two = [40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30] //I get this right
let three = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6] //I get this wrong
let four = [1, 4, 10, 4, 2]  // I get this wrong


//EXPECTED OUTCOMES
console.log(solution(one)) => false;
console.log(solution(two)) => false;
console.log(solution(three)) => true;
console.log(solution(four)) => false;
```

FYI: This is not for an assignment or test

Comment: can you provide us with the expected outputs?

Comment: @TroudiGhaith I have added my expected outputs

Comment: your just need to remove this line `return newArr`

Comment: @Emm ... Regarding the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new array seems overkill. I would first define a function that verifies at which index a given array violates being incremental.

Then check if there is a second violation after that. If so, return false.

With just one violation, return true when it occurs between the first two or last two values in the array.

In all other cases, verify that removing either of the two involved values resolves the violation.

Code:

```js
// Return the index where the value is not greater than its predecessor
function violation(a, start=0) {
    for (let i = start + 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i - 1] >= a[i]) return i;
    }
    return 0;
}

function solution(a) {
    let i = violation(a);
    return !i || !violation(a, i) && (i==1 || i==a.length-1 
                                     || a[i-2] < a[i] || a[i-1] < a[i+1]);
}

//TEST CASES
let tests = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6],
    [40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 10, 4, 2]
];

for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(solution(test));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The next provided solution uses an [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) based approach where one would count the amount of violations of the OP's criteria / requirements for a possibly incremental array. Depending on whether a violation has taken place one would compare the current values against the most recent value which caused the violation or one would just simply compare two consecutive array items.

As soon as the maximum allowed violation count gets exceeded, `every` immediately exits / breaks its iteration with a `false` boolean return value which also becomes the return value of the below implemented `canBeMadeIncremental` function; otherwise the return value of both processes is `true`.

```js
function canBeMadeIncremental(arr) {
  let violationCount = 0;
  let comparisonValue = null;

  return arr.every((value, idx, arr) => {
    let isAchievable = true;

    if (idx >= 1) {
      comparisonValue = comparisonValue ?? arr[idx - 1];

      if (comparisonValue >= value) {
        ++violationCount;
      } else {
        comparisonValue = null;
      }
      isAchievable = (violationCount <= 1);
    }
    return isAchievable;
  });
}

console.log(
  "canBeMadeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6]) ?..",
  canBeMadeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6]) // false
);
console.log(
  "canBeMadeIncremental([40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30]) ?..",
  canBeMadeIncremental([40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30]) // false
);
console.log(
  "canBeMadeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]) ?..",
  canBeMadeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]) // true
);
console.log(
  "canBeMadeIncremental([1, 4, 10, 4, 2]) ?..",
  canBeMadeIncremental([1, 4, 10, 4, 2]) // false
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The above code example could be easily refactored into a more generic function which provides data about whether an incremental array is possible and if yes, how to achieve it (e.g. which index / indices need/s to be removed) ...

```js
function howToMakeIncremental(arr) {
  let isAchievable = true;

  let comparisonValue = null;
  let violationCount = 0;

  const violatingIndexList = [];

  arr.every((value, idx, arr) => {
    if (idx >= 1) {
      comparisonValue = comparisonValue ?? arr[idx - 1];

      if (comparisonValue >= value) {

        violatingIndexList.push(idx);

        ++violationCount;
      } else {
        comparisonValue = null;
      }
      isAchievable = (violationCount <= 1);
    }
    return isAchievable;
  });
  const howTo = { isAchievable };

  if (isAchievable) {
    howTo.violatingIndexList = violatingIndexList;
  }
  return howTo;
}

console.log(
  "howToMakeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6]) ?..",
  howToMakeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6]) // { isAchievable: false }
);
console.log(
  "howToMakeIncremental([40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30]) ?..",
  howToMakeIncremental([40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30]) // { isAchievable: false }
);
console.log(
  "howToMakeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]) ?..",
  howToMakeIncremental([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]) // { isAchievable: true, violatingIndexList: [4] }
);
console.log(
  "howToMakeIncremental([1, 4, 10, 4, 2]) ?..",
  howToMakeIncremental([1, 4, 10, 4, 2]) // { isAchievable: false }
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing with your logic just remove the first return

```
function solution(sequence) {
let newArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
    sequence[i] < sequence[i+1] ? newArr.push(true) 
        : sequence[i+1] < sequence[i-1] ? newArr.push('very false')
            :newArr.push(false)
}
// return newArr
return (newArr.filter(i => i === false).length) > 1 || ( (newArr.includes('very 
    false')) && (newArr[newArr.length - 1] !== 'very false')) || ( 
    newArr.includes(false) && newArr.includes('very false')) ? false : true;
}
//TEST CASES
let one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6]
let two = [40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30]
let three = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6] 
let four = [1, 4, 10, 4, 2]  

console.log(solution(one));
console.log(solution(two));
console.log(solution(three));
console.log(solution(four));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was actually a typo. I still get  a few test cases incorrect - the one's I specified

Comment: the image's outputs match your expected ones

Comment: Running the currently provided code is not possible due to a ... `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` ... which is caused by malformed code.

Comment: @PeterSeliger when you copy-paste the code, you need to remove the break-line between 'very false' at line 9 which is causing that error, it was added when I posted the answer

Comment: @TroudiGhaith ... I know, and thus it is actually your task to do in order to provide non breaking code.